# After importing an empty repo to IntelliJ, how to create a maven project under the branch?

Tags: java, git, maven, intellij-idea, gitlab

I'm new to Maven and Gitlab, been messing around all day with it now. So here's what I did:

- created a new project repo in Gitlab, pushed two files in master branch (Read.me and another json file), created dev branch for this repo;
- Went back to Intellij, Imported this repo via 'Project from version control', I wanted to do some testing for a Maven plugin in an existing pom file, so I copied that pom file in this project folder, but pom.xml appearing in red, and when I tried to create a Java class file, it also appearing in red, I really don't know what to do now.

Is it because I didn't create a Maven project in this folder so IntelliJ don't recognize the pom file and java file? I tried to create a new project but this new one has nothing to do with my new-added repo in Gitlab. Can someone tell me what to do? Many thanks.

If this is not the proper way to do this, what is the better way to do this in a more sensible and easier way?

Comment: don't do that. just create a new maven project in the directory you have your git project under.

Comment: @Stultuske If I create a new maven project in the directory and how can I link to my new-added gitlab repo?

Comment: it already is. the moment you do a git status then, you'll see that all the new files are seen as new files in the project. just add, commit and push

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly - red file means that file is not under version control.

Visit for more information:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/adding-files-to-version-control.html
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/set-up-a-git-repository.html

Comment: Hi this seems solved my problem, now both of them turn into green (I guess normally the color would be white?)

Comment: Right color before commit (by default) is green so everything is ok.

Comment: Thank you very much